# Making an equation separable via a change of coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose I have some general function $f(x,y)$, a function of the coordinates $x$ and $y$.

Does a general procedure exist for finding a transformation to new coordinates $x'$, $y'$ such that the function becomes separable, i.e. can be written $h(x') + g(y')$?

I appreciate that in any specific case, one may be able to look at the expression and determine an appropriate coordinate transformation by inspection. I am more interested if a general procedure does exist.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $g(x')+h(y')$? (You already used $f$ for $f(x,y)$.)

Comment: Yes sorry! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Not one that works for every function. For example, suppose $f$ is constant  and nonzero, $f\equiv c\neq 0$. But then $f(x,y)=c$, while $f(x')+f(y')=c+c=2c\neq c$.